# Add level to column from Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe on which I'd like to add a level of columns.
The correct new level of column can be found using my_dict.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abcde'), data={'A': range(5), 'B': range(5)})
my_dict = {"B": "BB","A": "AA","C": "CC"}
```

This is what I expect:

```
Out[92]: 
   A  B
   AA BB
a  0  0
b  1  1
c  2  2
d  3  3
e  4  4
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do `df.columns.map` then convert to Multiindex

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((df.columns,df.columns.map(my_dict)))
```

---

```
   A  B
  AA BB
a  0  0
b  1  1
c  2  2
d  3  3
e  4  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) with assign back to columns names by nested lists - if no match get `NaN`:

```
df.columns = [df.columns, df.columns.map(my_dict)]
print (df)
   A  B
  AA BB
a  0  0
b  1  1
c  2  2
d  3  3
e  4  4
```

Solution with `rename` - if no match get original values:

```
df.columns = [df.columns, df.rename(columns=my_dict).columns]
```

---

```
df.columns = [df.columns, df.columns]

df = df.rename(columns=my_dict, level=1)
```

Test for not match:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=list('abcde'), data={'A': range(5), 'B': range(5), 'D': range(5)})
my_dict = {"B": "BB","A": "AA","C": "CC"}


df.columns = [df.columns, df.columns.map(my_dict)]
print (df)
   A  B   D
  AA BB NaN
a  0  0   0
b  1  1   1
c  2  2   2
d  3  3   3
e  4  4   4
```

---

```
df.columns = [df.columns, df.columns]
df = df.rename(columns=my_dict, level=1)

#df.columns = [df.columns, df.rename(columns=my_dict).columns]
print (df)
   A  B  D
  AA BB  D
a  0  0  0
b  1  1  1
c  2  2  2
d  3  3  3
e  4  4  4
```